# Qt: Setting gradient on Layout

Tags: qt, background, pyqt

I have a QHBoxLayout with several items in it.  In the space occupied by the QHBoxLayout, I want a vertical gradient from black to white (behind the items in the QHBoxLayout).  However:

- QHBoxLayouts do not have style sheets, so that's out
- QHBoxLayouts do not have palettes, so that's out

And these are the only two methods of setting gradients that I've found (they were all intended to work on widgets).  I tried setting the stylesheet of the parent widget to include:

```
QHBoxLayout {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to see if css could be worked in that way, but this does nothing.

Is it possible to give a layout a background gradient with Qt?

(I am using PyQt5, if that's relevant)

Comment: I'm no expert to PyQt5, but plain Qt. In there it is possible to add a widget behind  the layout which then gets the gradient. Maybe you can translate this to PyQt5?

Comment: ... The idea of circumventing the layout entirely never occurred to me.  Do you want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?  And thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert to PyQt, but in plain Qt you can put your `QHBoxLayout` inside a `QWidget` and then apply a layout to the widget (the buttons above the designer).

[image]

This is what the object tree looks like when done (the selected item has the gradient)

[image: Visual representation of widget tree]

And this is how my little mock up came out. (If you like the buttons to be non-transparent, add a stylesheet for the background)

[image: end result]